# Soti Surf As Supported Browser For Okta Android SDK

Tags: android, single-sign-on, okta, okta-api, soti

We are developing Okta integration with our Android App using the [Okta SDK](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/sign-into-mobile-app/android/sign-in-page/).

The app successfully authenticates when Chrome is used as the supporting browser.

However, we are unable to use Chrome as users are able to freely browse the internet, something that we wish to prohibit.

We use SOTI and are able to whitelist the addresses needed using [SOTI Surf](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.soti.surf) however, despite us adding this as a supported browser, the browser fails to launch with the error "No compatible browsers found":

```
WebAuthClient client = new Okta.WebAuthBuilder()
        .withConfig(config)
        .withContext(this)
        .withStorage(new SharedPreferenceStorage(this))
        .withCallbackExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
        .withTabColor(Color.BLUE)
        .supportedBrowsers("com.android.chrome", "org.mozilla.firefox", "net.soti.surf")
        .create();
```

Copying the link generated by the APK from Chrome into SOTI Surf authenticates successfully and returns the user to our app - the problem is launching it.

Any ideas how we can either:

1. Successfully launch SOTI Surf, or
2. Launch Chrome but remove the menu bar completely.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had confirmed by SOTI, that SOTI Surf doesn’t not support Chrome Custom Tabs - which is required under the Okta SDK.

It is possible to use Chrome and apply web filtering using SOTI, however the device needs to be on Android Enterprise, not Android Plus.